# Make innosetup copy the full folder instead of only its content

Tags: inno-setup

How to make innoSetup copy the full folder instead of copying the content of the folder only? 
I want to add my resources folder to the setup :

```
Source: "C:\Users\youss\eclipse-workspace\myApp\resources\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

but what happens is that when I install the app I can't find the root folder (resources), all what I find is its content, what breaks the app (all the paths to the resources become invalid)

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your destination (`DestDir`) to include the folder:

```
Source: "C:\Users\youss\eclipse-workspace\myApp\resources\*"; DestDir: "{app}\resources"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```